# Wireless not connecting in ubuntu Mate (16.06)

Tags: networking, mate, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I recently installed ubuntu Mate on my dell inspiron 15R (N5110). Previously I was running ubuntu + unity. Post the install my wireless isn't connecting to the wifi (ethernet works though). I have tried searching on a lot of forums but couldn't come up with any solution, kindly help if possible.

`psn13147` is my wifi ESSID. I ran the wireless diagnostic script i found on one of the ubuntu forums and have put in the parts that might be relevant. If any other output is needed, please let me know.

```
##### dmesg #############################

[  103.227180] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]>
[  103.230578] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  103.242411] wlp9s0: authenticated
[  103.244663] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  103.251528] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  103.263182] wlp9s0: associated
[  103.263298] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
[  106.499415] wlp9s0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[  107.015821] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]>
[  107.017287] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  107.026903] wlp9s0: authenticated
[  107.028421] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  107.063694] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 2/3)
[  107.098165] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 3/3)
[  107.130881] wlp9s0: association with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> timed out
[  108.040236] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]>
[  108.041344] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  108.067221] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 2/3)
[  108.088332] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 3/3)
[  108.111303] wlp9s0: authentication with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> timed out
[  130.873623] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]>
[  130.874701] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[  130.900616] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 2/3)
[  130.918906] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> (try 3/3)
[  130.939592] wlp9s0: authentication with <MAC 'psn13147' [AC2]> timed out
[  149.047781] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[  280.805930] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
[  280.805957] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::703b:86a4:5e65:5f1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29522484 (29.5 MB)  TX bytes:1092444 (1.0 MB)

wlp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:410 (410.0 B)  TX bytes:3464 (3.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

##### lspci #############################

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:04b0]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/psn13147]] (600 root)
[connection] id=psn13147 | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu-mate:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=psn13147
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/psn13147 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=psn13147 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:shekhar:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=psn13147
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

### dmesg 
        [   17.352305] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
    [   18.073971] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
    [   18.073982] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
    [   18.073987] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
    [   18.073993] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
    [   18.074065] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [   18.143944] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
    [   18.279036] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
    [   32.022839] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [   32.023051] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.029806] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.029912] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [   32.099043] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.105801] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [   32.105908] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [   32.161883] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [   33.104552] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [  103.227180] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [  103.230578] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  103.242411] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [  103.244663] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  103.251528] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [  103.263182] wlp9s0: associated
    [  103.263298] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [  106.499415] wlp9s0: deauthenticated from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
    [  107.015821] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [  107.017287] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  107.026903] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [  107.028421] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  107.063694] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [  107.098165] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [  107.130881] wlp9s0: association with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [  108.040236] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [  108.041344] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  108.067221] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [  108.088332] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [  108.111303] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [  130.873623] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [  130.874701] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  130.900616] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [  130.918906] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [  130.939592] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [  149.047781] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [  826.115839] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [  826.116983] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  826.126913] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [  826.128371] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [  826.140167] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [  826.149556] wlp9s0: associated
    [  826.149664] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [ 1226.263935] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 1226.265170] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1226.285126] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 1226.286961] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1226.293361] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 1226.302052] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 1260.259853] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 1260.260881] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1260.280321] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 1260.283831] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1260.294983] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 1260.303747] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 1263.535929] wlp9s0: deauthenticated from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
    [ 1264.046236] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 1264.047287] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1264.049679] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 1264.052391] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 1264.087120] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 1264.096947] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 1264.099224] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 1270.295439] wlp9s0: deauthenticated from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
    [ 1295.441183] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 4707.415960] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 4707.419068] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 4707.425785] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 4707.425890] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [ 4707.499180] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 4707.505931] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 4707.506044] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [ 4707.561582] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 4707.823142] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 4810.156756] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 4810.157815] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 4810.160479] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 4810.161277] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 4810.170993] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 4810.173818] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 4810.173941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [ 4909.677602] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 4917.939126] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5115.557444] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
    [ 5115.574184] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
    [ 5115.574193] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
    [ 5115.574198] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
    [ 5115.574204] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
    [ 5115.574278] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5115.580990] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
    [ 5115.592819] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
    [ 5115.603862] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
    [ 5115.638412] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5122.062656] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
    [ 5122.066692] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5122.073435] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5122.073540] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [ 5122.140997] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5122.147734] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
    [ 5122.147840] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
    [ 5122.203333] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5122.254828] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5126.016694] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5126.019229] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5126.036801] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 5126.037265] wlp9s0: waiting for beacon from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5126.088349] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5126.092960] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 5126.100610] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 5126.100743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [ 5164.139242] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5164.139972] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5164.168025] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5164.190935] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5164.221335] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5165.061459] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5165.062081] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5165.082863] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5165.105480] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5165.125699] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5166.494538] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5166.495167] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5166.514627] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5166.532644] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5166.555337] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5177.245889] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5177.246537] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5177.265749] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5177.289833] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5177.313248] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5178.667636] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5190.721186] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5207.758433] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5207.759599] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5207.762212] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 5207.765515] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5207.771859] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 5207.774016] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 5207.774120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [ 5274.825431] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5274.826083] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5274.845136] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5274.862699] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5274.887203] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5275.746934] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5275.747643] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5275.768389] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5275.793013] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5275.811088] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5277.180864] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5277.181678] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5277.200878] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5277.224903] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5277.247393] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5289.657788] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5290.161444] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5290.162607] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5290.182268] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 2/3)
    [ 5290.201754] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 3/3)
    [ 5290.221417] wlp9s0: authentication with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 timed out
    [ 5315.601842] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
    [ 5376.067602] wlp9s0: authenticate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14
    [ 5376.068924] wlp9s0: send auth to 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5376.075343] wlp9s0: authenticated
    [ 5376.077937] wlp9s0: associate with 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (try 1/3)
    [ 5376.081350] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [ 5376.083710] wlp9s0: associated
    [ 5376.083835] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
    [ 5413.155671] wlp9s0: deauthenticating from 0c:d2:b5:24:a4:14 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    [ 5448.634806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: `iwlist scan` shows my wifi essid at times but mostly shows `No scan results`.  The menu bar wifi icon doesn't show any wifi network available at all.

Comment: Please add: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp`

Comment: Disabling 802.11n should fix it.

Comment: @Pilot6: I switched off the wifi, disabled 802.11n and retried. It connected to the wifi but disconnected in 30 sec. chili555: I updated the logs with that one